# At near light speeds, are small objects in your path a problem?

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, collision, estimation, rocket-science

A mental exercise: A space ship is accelerating toward me from far away. As it approaches me, I can observe its acceleration. This high speed ship keeps accelerating faster toward the speed of light. At some point, its apparent acceleration changes to a deceleration and slows more and more. Say, for the sake of argument, that the ships top speed is such that from my perspective, it only seems to be moving around, say, 500 mph (or something relatively slow). As it nears me and flies by, I move along side of it and match its speed flying side by side. As we fly along there are two small pebbles (1/4 inch in diameter) in our path ahead. We collide with them. The small pebble I collide with bounces off my ship.

1. Does the small pebble the other ship collides with destroy the ship (assuming it doesn't have any way to deflect it)?
2. If I flung a baseball at the ship from my ship and it hit the other ship, would it destroy the ship as well with a huge impact?

EDIT: In essence what I'm asking is what's the difference between me hitting the pebble and the other ship hitting the pebble (which is at near light speed). Clearly there would have to be a different outcome. The other ship is hitting it at near the speed of light which I would think would spell disaster for that ship, but not mine, even though we're flying along side each other.

Comment: It's not horribly clear to me what you're asking.  The big limiting factor in these things is relative speed.  For reference, a very, very fast bullet travels at 1 km/s.  So, your pebble would have roughly the same effect as a bullet travelling at similar speed.  Since the two spaceships are at rest with respect to each other, the baseball will have roughly the same effect as throwing a baseball on the ground.

Comment: ^Agreed. Also, I think you're confused by the fact your KE can indeed vary based on your choice of inertial frame. Much like velocity, the KE of an object is relative to the observer. So, the baseball will not cause (too) much damage.

Comment: @shortstheory Then the baseball should impact the light speed ship with high inertia just as the pebble does. It wouldn't make much sense to say that the pebble would impact the ship with devastating impact, but the baseball wouldn't. From the light speed ship's perspective, the baseball is being hurled at the ship at a very high rate of speed.

Comment: @MatthewMoon, I don't quite understand what you mean by _"high inertia"_. Won't the impact of collision depend on the relative velocity of the bodies? Discounting relativistic effects (even though the question suggests otherwise), the impulse felt by the other spaceship is likely to not be very high as the change in momentum will be much less than if it was hit by the baseball traveling very fast while at rest.

Comment: @shortstheory When I hurl the baseball at the other ship, from that other ship's perspective, it's being hurled at an extremely high rate of speed, yes? That's my thinking. And when that baseball impacts that ship, would it not impact it with devastating effects? But from the ball's perspective, it's hitting the ship at a speed that my arm can throw, i.e., the ball wouldn't be destroyed with the impact. And, in regards to my first question, I would think that hitting a pebble at near light speed would obliterate that ship instantly. So why wouldn't the ball do the same?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but your question is flawed.

You said that by the time of the impact, you caught up to the other ship such that it has no velocity relative to you (matching speed).

Assuming your ship isn't built any more resiliently than theirs, if the impact caused no damage to your ship, then there's no reason to expect that it will cause any damage to theirs either.

---

That being said, I can tell that your intent was probably to ask about an impact at low velocity vs the same impact at a relativistic velocity. In that case, yes - the other ship will likely experience severe damage from such an impact. The precise details would require more information.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think that the ship's apparent acceleration turns into deceleration? I think this is the source of your confusion. If the ship remains accelerating at a constant rate relative to its occupants, then its acceleration relative to you must slow as it approaches c, but it will not drop below 0.

To answer the question in your title, if you hit a small object the damage done depends on the relative speed of you and the object. If the relative speed is near c, then yes, it's a big problem. If the relative speed is small, then it's only a small problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, my question was flawed here. I conflated two ideas: 1. A ship being pulled into a black hole accelerating towards 'c' as it gets closer to the event horizon. And, 2. A ship accelerating on its own with no gravitational effect around it. To an observer those two things appear very different. An observer sees the ship falling into a black hole decelerate as it gets closer (because of the gravitational field around the ship). But a ship accelerating on its own has no such apparent decelerating effect. Apologies for completely confusing everyone.